# CSS margin-top issue - element needs 100% width, otherwise renders badly?

Tags: html, css

I'll try to explain this as simply as possible.

Let's say I have a logo with the dimensions 150px in width by 40px in height, and I want to contain it at the top of a 820px wide container. In order to use the `margin-top` property
on the content below, I find myself nesting `<div="logo></div>` within another container that has the width set to 100%, like so;

```
<div id="logo_width">
  <div id="logo"></div>
</div>
```

So far, this has been fine for me as it gets the job done, however I still believe that `<div id="logo_width">` (the container with the width set to 100%) is overhead, unneeded, and that there's a better way to be able to use the `margin` property properly on content below the logo without it messing up because no container above it has the width of 100%.

Perhaps I'm wrong, but if someone could tell me a way to get around this (if possible), so that I need only have `<div id="logo"></div>` without nesting it, I would very very much appreciate it :)!!

Comment: would need more html (or better yet a live demo) for a definitive answer.

Comment: Alright, I'll upload it to JSFiddle or something ASAP.

Comment: It's hard to tell without more information on your markup, but it appears that you are using another element to create an artificial boundary to bound another element's padding.

Comment: I've just attempted it and there doesn't seem to be an issue now, at least as far as I can test (I think what happened was that I used to have this issue, and creating another element to create an artificial boundary as @Jared Farrish mentioned, back when I really didn't know what I was doing, and just carried on the practice assuming it was needed (until now)). My apologies everyone, but thanks for your input!

Comment: @Pixelatron np :) always glad to help.  If you encounter any other problems don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the issue is, but this works.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="logo"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container{
    width:820px;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:400px;
}

#logo{
    width:150px;
    border:1px solid green;
    height:40px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/7WQZm/

In this example, `#container` is your 820px container.  `div#logo-width` is removed.